# How to handle HttpClientErrorException?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-rest

I have a REST service which I handle the exception as follows and return a VndErrors object.

```
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidOperationException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public VndErrors handleException(InvalidOperationException ex) {
    return new VndErrors("Invalid operation",ex.getMessage());
}
```

I consume this service as follows. Due to passing wrong url, I received  HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException. But in the REST service side I did not wrap this exception with VndErrors since it is not an exception I throw. It is thrown by Spring. My catch block catches this exception and then tries to parse the string as VndErrors and gets exception as it is not wrapped. My question is how should we approach to this situation? Any suggestion?

```
    ResponseEntity<List> responseEntity = null;
    try {
        responseEntity = template.getForEntity(baseUrl, List.class, urlVariables);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        VndErrors errors = null;
        try {
            errors = getJSonStringAsVndErrors(ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new  RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }

        String message = errors.iterator().next().getMessage();
        throw new RuntimeException(message);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure where the exception is being caught (`HttpClientErrorException` or `IOException`)  but either catch something more specific (`InvalidOperationException`) or add some logic to verify what you're catching contains the `VndErrors`

Comment: And it's not good practice to throw `RuntimeException`. Extend it, and give the exception a meaningful name.